# Проблема с Denwer

Tags: denwer, dle

Народ, у меня ошибка появляется после запуска сервера. Не могу понять в чём причина. Помогите разобраться.

> `(OS 10048)╬с√ўэю ЁрчЁх°рхЄё  юфэю шёяюы№чютрэшх рфЁхёр ёюъхЄр (яЁюЄюъюы/ёхЄхтющ
> рфЁхё/яюЁЄ).  : make_sock: could not bind to address 127.0.0.1:80
> no listening sockets available, shutting down
> Unable to open logs
> Note the errors or messages above, and press the <ESC> key to exit.  18...`

Скайп не включен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

:80 занят другим приложением и апачь выплёвывает.

Открываем **httpd.conf**, ищем там строку Listen xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 или Listen 80 
 Меняем 80 на номер другого порта. Например, 8080. 
 Перезапускаем апач.

Comment: не помогло((

Comment: Апач перезапускал? Выполнить в командной строке "netstat -anb" и посмотреть какой процес занмает тот порт который запрашивает апач.

Comment: netstat -anb ввожу появляется командная строка и тут же исчезает

Answer (score 0):

введи для начала cmd, нажми enter. а уж потом netstat - -anb
обязательно с 2-я дефисами!